# How does the communicator work in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek

After re-watching most of the old Star Trek shows, I noticed something after many episodes. When they communicate in the show most times they hit their communicator, after responding the receiver of the original transmission would just stop speaking to the transmitter. My question is do the communications just stop or is there a length of time the communications stay open. I have seen in some episodes that they receiver will hit the comm badge again to end the communication.

It seems that there would be a standard to adhere to in Starfleet, but the task seems so erratic in the shows.

Comment: Aww, I was hoping this would address the physics of the things TOS communicators could do, and be abused into doing (2 devices + Spock = sonic disruptor, etc.).  Less impressive in the days of satellite phones, of course...

Comment: I've removed the work specific tags assuming you're asking about all of ST

Comment: The method he describes is specific to TNG and later commbadges.  TOS used the "flip phone" communicators, that clearly shut off when the flip was closed.

Comment: on a less serious note: the comminicators work however they need to for a given episode ;)